# MySQL: GROUP BY range in 2 dimensions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some survey data in the format: id, ans1, ans2.

ans1 and ans2 are the surveyees' ratings of two foods out of 10. I can use a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), ans1, ans2 FROM survey GROUP BY ans1, ans2;
```

in order to see how responses correlate. This has two problems. Ideally though, I'd like be able to draw out the data using an SQL query to show me how surveyees responses correlated when thinking of responses like low, medium and high (e.g. 1-3, 4-7, 8-10). I'd also like it to print out 0 when there are 0 entries for (ans1, ans2) [I'm aware it's not coming up because the data is not there].

It would also be really cool if this could pretty print a grid in SQL too, but I fear that may be asking too much!

Comment: What's the question?  Desired output with sample data would be helpful too.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: If you want to do statistical analysis on results, I would recommend a statistical package (SAS, SPSS, R, for instance) or even a spreadsheet (this doesn't seem too complicated).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood your question.

In my opinion you can use [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). I have prepared example for you [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d2ea/16/0)

Comment: This is appropriate as a comment but not as an answer.